# ASP .NET Scaffolding ignoring list data structures?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, scaffolding

I'm trying to learn ASP .NET by creating a sample website, and have a problem. Suppose I have the following classes:

```
public class Player
{
    public string name {get; set;}
    public int age {get; set;}
    public double salary {get; set;}
    public string gender {get; set;}
    public DateTime contractSignDate {get; set;}
}

public class Team
{
    public string teamName {get; set;}
    public string sportPlayed {get; set;}
    public List<Player> players {get; set;}
}
```

Now if I try to use Scaffolding in VS2013 to create controller and CRUD pages around the Model Team, but the pages will only have fields for `teamName` and `sportPlayed`. `players` List control will not be catered for. Ideally speaking, when I'm creating a new team, I'd like a way to define new Players and add them to that team as well. This can be either through Player addition controls on the Team Create page, or maybe a button such as 'Manage Players' which when clicked, opens a small popup where Players can be added. How can this be achieved while using Scaffolding ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could fix it by using a partial view where you can use scaffolding(Create template) to create a new player.

Comment: I'm aware what a partial view is, but I didn't understand the second part of your sentence.

Comment: You can create a new player, in a partial view.

Comment: You can create a new player, in a partial view. and show the partial view in you create view for Team.   the manual way is described here [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/855577/List-of-Model-Object-Post-to-Controller-in-ASP-NET)